# Add target=_blank to one link in JS file for wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hyperlink

I need to have the below code changed to open the google maps link in a new window when clicked.

I'm new to this so be nice please :)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker, 'click', function() {
                            window.location.href = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q='+companyPos;
                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker, 'click', function() {
                       window.open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q='+companyPos, '_blank');
                            });
```

This will open a link in new Window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the users browsers to open something in a new tab, but the closest you'll get is something like this, that will open in a new tab if the browser doesn't disallow it for some reason

```
google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker, 'click', function() {
  var map = window.open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q='+companyPos, '_blank');
  map.focus();
});
```